# tabs in string have different size

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
String t = "\"A\tB\tC\"";
String s = "A\tB\tC";

System.out.println(t);
System.out.println(s);
```

where `t` prints this:

```
"A      B       C"
```

and the tab spaces between "A e B is 6 spaces while tab spaces between B and C" is 7 spaces.

Instead `s` prints this:

```
A       B       C
```

and the tab spaces between A e B is 7 spaces and tab spaces between B and C is also 7 spaces.

Why, in the first string, does tab spaces have different sizes?

Comment: tab and spaces are not equivalent. Try the same on any text editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends entirely on the program ("console" or "shell") where the Java program is running, it has nothing to do with Java.

Most shells implement tabs much like a typewriter would. Because you have the `"` prior to the `A`, it's already one character into the tab stop. But `B` appears right on the tab stop, so there's more room between it and `C`.

E.g., note the `+` below representing tab stops at exactly 8 characters each, and your two strings:

```
+       +       +       +       +       +       +
"A      B       C"
A       B       C
```

Answer (score 2):

Tab is a tab - it's not an equivalent of some number of spaces. The way how it is displayed and alligned is up to the console.

Answer (score 2):

When you tab you go for the next, fixed width, position.

If those fixed position for tab are (8 characters), while you are on position 9 to 15, if you tab you will go to the position 16.

This is what is hapenning on your java output.

Answer (score 1):

Tab size is 8 characters and alignment is performed using multiples of 8 such that B is aligned at 8 characters from the margin and C is aligned 16 characters from the margin in both cases.

Comment: Sometimes a tab is 8, sometimes it's 4, ... it depends.

Comment: I agree, 4 and 8 are the most used values. In this particular case is 8.

Answer (score 0):

In Java `\t` (tab) is having a specific size of whitespaces. When you use `\t` in Java it places a cursor after the 8th position. If you have written 2 words and then append `\t` the cursor will be on 6th position.