# sWhat will be the explaination of output of the below mentioned C problem?

Tags: output

What will be the output of the following programs:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        printf("ab\tab\tab\ba");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why can you not run the code yourself and see? Apart from that, the title of your Question doesn't make it easy to find in a search.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it says "What will be the output of the below mentioned C problem?". There is not issue with code but OP just want to know output.

Comment: You can use [Ideone](https://ideone.com/mWVhep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result would be `ab    ab    aa`.
This is because the string contains certain characters("ab **\t** ab  **\t**  ab  **\b**  a") that the program will detect. [`\t`](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=%5Ct&redirect=no)(This is tab, It will usually add four spaces in its spot) and [`\b`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5Cb)( means backspace, so it will delete the previous character in the string).

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    printf("ab\tabc\tabcda");
    return 0;
    }                                                 
    output is: ab      abc     abcda      ,,,,  I am not getting why the space  in between the ouptut is not of uniform width.

Comment: Did you post the exact message you receive? If so, that is a bit strange, however it might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447255/tabs-in-string-have-different-size) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646039/printf-t-option). It probably is a terminal issue, and not the code itself.